# Can't perform Linq query from multiple tables mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am beginner in linq and I am trying to write linq query to get data from multiple tables

```
IQueryable<ESSRequest> ESSRequest = from essrequest in db.ESSRequest
                                    join emps in db.HrEmpS on essrequest.HrEmp_no equals emps.HrEmp_no
                                    join emp in db.HrEmp on emps.Emp_no equals emp.Emp_no
                                    where essrequest.Next_Approval == user_id
                                    select new { essrequest, emp_name=emp.Emp_Name};
```

I got the following error

> Error 71  Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#2>' to
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable<ESSCS.Models.ESSRequest>'. An explicit
>   conversion exists (are you missing a
>   cast?)    E:\MVC\ESSCS\ESSCS\Controllers\RequestController.cs 138 53  ESSCS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a query of an anonymous type rather than the actual type specified in the variable. so instead of creating a `IQueryable<ESSRequest>` you are creating a `IQueryable<AnonymousTypeX>`. Instead, when you do your `select`, specify the type there or in your case, it looks like you can simply select `essrequest`. If you also want to include the `Emp_name` value, you will either have to use the anonymous type or create another model class to use.

```
IQueryable<ESSRequest> ESSRequest = from essrequest in db.ESSRequest
                                    join emps in db.HrEmpS on essrequest.HrEmp_no equals emps.HrEmp_no
                                    join emp in db.HrEmp on emps.Emp_no equals emp.Emp_no
                                    where essrequest.Next_Approval == user_id
                                    select essrequest;
```

Or if you need the value of `Emp_Name`, create a class like this:

```
private class RequestAndName
{
    public ESSRequest ESSRequest { get; set; }
    public string Emp_Name { get; set; }
}
```

And populate it like this:

```
IQueryable<RequestAndName> ESSRequest = from essrequest in db.ESSRequest
                                        join emps in db.HrEmpS on essrequest.HrEmp_no equals emps.HrEmp_no
                                        join emp in db.HrEmp on emps.Emp_no equals emp.Emp_no
                                        where essrequest.Next_Approval == user_id
                                        select new RequestAndName
                                        {
                                            ESSRequest = essrequest,
                                            Emp_Name = emp.Emp_Name
                                        };
```

Answer (score 2):

The type of your Class/Object on both sides of you equation on not same.

On Left Hand side you have: `IQueryable<ESSRequest>`

On Right Hand side you have an anonymous type, you are generating using LINQ: `select new { essrequest, emp_name=emp.Emp_Name};`

The both have to be same type.

```
IQueryable<ESSRequest> ESSRequest = from essrequest in db.ESSRequest
                                    join emps in db.HrEmpS on essrequest.HrEmp_no equals emps.HrEmp_no
                                    join emp in db.HrEmp on emps.Emp_no equals emp.Emp_no
                                    where essrequest.Next_Approval == user_id
                                    select essrequest;
```

Then if you need the Anonymous type you can do this, after above linq use this:

```
var aType = ESSRequest.Select(s => new { Employee = (s), emp_name = s.Emp_Name });
```

Then you can Access it like this:

```
foreach( var employee in aType)
{
var empNamefromObject = employee.Employee.Emp_Name;
var empName = employee.Emp_Name;
}
```